# Transmitting input tag value in to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, paypal

I have created a variable to carry the value of the amount which is sent to the checkout page. It seems that the checkout experience is not recognizing the variable.

```
 <input type="number" id="challenge_stake" name="stake"  required = "true" />     
<button type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" onclick="myFunction();">Pay Now</button> 
 ...  
         <div id="paypal-button-container">

         </div>

         <input name="forPaypal" type="number" value="0" id="forPaypal">           

<script>
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('forPaypal').value);     
    paypal.Buttons({
        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: x
                    }
                }]
            });
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>

<script> function myFunction() {
            var amount = 
parseFloat(document.getElementById('challenge_stake').value);         
document.getElementById('forPaypal').value = amount;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, the value of `x` will be always to `0`. Change your `createOrder` function to following:

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
   return actions.order.create({
       purchase_units: [{
           amount: {
               value: parseFloat(document.getElementById('forPaypal').value)
           }
       }]
   }
}
```

Comment: Smart answer Gopal! Why does it work now? Is it because of the dynamic typing nature of javascript or what?

Comment: Yes, in your earlier code, the value of x is calculated where your page is loaded, but in the new code, it calculates every time you click the Paypal button.

Comment: I agree and I considered that, however the myFunction() function is called and I presumed that it would set the value of the forPaypal input tag at load time.

Comment: It changes the value of the input field not the value of `x` and you were using `x`.

Comment: so that is why you used the full expression instead.